# jQuery: "Nested" visibility

Tags: jquery, visibility

I have a table with multiple `<tbody>` elements. At a given momement, certain `<tbody>` elements are visible and some are hidden, and I need to select only the visible ones.
I use jQuery's `:visible` selector.

Now the problem is that I need to perform that task before I display the table, AKA while the table is hidden, and then the `:visible` selector doesn't work.

**How can I select "visible" `<tbody>` elements while the table is hidden?**

Thanks.

Comment: What "task" do you speak of? What are you doing with these tbody elements? You can still use DOM operations if they have been appended, FYI.

Comment: How are the `<tbody>` elements hidden?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `.filter`:

```
$('tbody').filter(function() { return $(this).css('display') !== 'none'; })
```

Comment: is it display:none or visbility:hidden ?